# How to update a single column with multiple data in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am updating an oracle table, same column with multiple data. How do i write the code?

I run this code but had error..

I am replacing Boy with Girl, Black with White and Green with Color.

```
UPDATE BIG
SET
    FNAME = CASE
        WHEN FNAME = 'BOY' THEN 'GIRL'
        WHEN FNAME = 'BLACK' THEN 'WHITE'
        WHEN FNAME = 'GREEN' THEN 'COLOR'
    END;
```

I need to be able to write a single statement that can update same column with different and multiple data.

Comment: `I run this code but had error..` And the error message is? Your code looks all right

Comment: Lukasz, when i run the script it updates the columns alright but then it makes columns that were not update NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle `ELSE`(all rows will be updated some using A -> A (identity):

```
UPDATE BIG
SET
    FNAME = CASE FNAME
        WHEN 'BOY' THEN 'GIRL'
        WHEN 'BLACK' THEN 'WHITE'
        WHEN 'GREEN' THEN 'COLOR'
        ELSE FNAME
    END;
```

or better filter rows you want to update:

```
UPDATE BIG
SET
    FNAME = CASE
        WHEN FNAME = 'BOY' THEN 'GIRL'
        WHEN FNAME = 'BLACK' THEN 'WHITE'
        WHEN FNAME = 'GREEN' THEN 'COLOR'
    END;
WHERE FNAME IN('BOY', 'BLACK', 'GREEN');

<=>

UPDATE BIG
SET FNAME = DECODE(FNAME, 'BOY', 'GIRL', 'BLACK', 'WHITE', 'GREEN', 'COLOR')
WHERE FNAME IN('BOY', 'BLACK', 'GREEN');
```

Comment: Lukasz Szozda i really appreciate it , all three works well.